# Learndash - Adding Topic categories into <body class="">

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I need to insert the topic categories of learndash into the `<body class="">` just like `<body class="ld-topic-categorie-one">`

The problem I have is that learndash is inserting the topic categories into the `<article>` tag, which gives me some limitations.

I can add learndash lessons to stardard wordpress categories. With following code I could insert the wordpress category into the `<body class="">`

```
function add_categories( $classes = '' ) {

$categories = get_the_category();
foreach( $categories as $category ) {
$classes[] = 'category-'.$category->slug;


}
 return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'body_class', 'add_categories' );
```

Now I still need a way to add topic categories into the body classes

thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I just installed the plugin "Custom Body Class" to add classes topics.
It works just fine.

But if someone of you knows a solution that works without a separate plugin I would be happy to hear from you.